# SharePoint Designer workflow that updates a field to a value after a submission or edit with an attachment

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow, list-workflow

Is there a way to update a field within SharePoint Designer workflow whenever an attachment is added to a submission or edit?

So someone submits a new form or an edit. They add an attachment. They click submit. Then that action updates a field to a value like "Yes" or "Attached"

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you already using any workflow on this particular SharePoint list?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 and will be using SharePoint 2013 Designer.